# Moving Azure Instance to AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, migration

I have received $200 credit to host my 2 Windows Azure Cloud projects on AWS. Just wondering what the quick and dirty process is to migrate my Visual studio projects to being published on the AWS cloud?

I could seem to find much documentation available, with the exception that apparently it's possible.

Comment: I currently host 1 ASP.net MVC6 Web services instance and 1 BLOB Cloud image storage instance. I would ideally like to move both over to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Cloud Services (web role), an Azure Web Site, or a VM?  Depending on how the ASP.NET MVC code is written, you could provision whatever compute capability you need in AWS and deploy there.

The blob storage would likely be the problem.  That is unless the code has an abstraction layer to isolate the app from storage implementation details.  Azure blob storage and whatever you using in AWS have different platform APIs.

Comment: I'm using one Cloud service and one Azure Website.

Yea I was afraid that the BLOB storage was a Azure Specific API, though it shouldnt be too hard to convert the logic to use an AWS equivalenence. What do you mean when you say 'Compute Capability'.

Comment: For example, EC2 instance, Beanstalk, etch. - whatever hosts your web app.

Comment: In follow up I found that EC3 was Azures BLOB storage equivalent, with just a different set of rules and process to access and use. Relatively easy to switch over.